# Why am I no longer in a Connected State in my blazor application server app?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, iis, telerik, blazor-server-side

My blazor server application is hosted on IIS, written in C#, using the Chrome browser, and with SQL server as the backend. My issue is that I have a modal page that gets information inputed into it, and the user clicks Ok to submit the data.  After submit, it closes the page and runs code on the calling page.  When it hits the following line of code ***await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync("CurrentInvestorPK", investorPK);***, I get an exception.  I believe this is not the issue but I don't understand why I'm all of sudden in a disconnected state.  Please see screen shot attached for error logging in dev tools (f12).  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

[Screenshot of error in Chrome DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCGNe.png)

Comment: This error only occurs on iis? or does it work fine locally? and do you have web sockets enabled in IIS?

Comment: Why are you using LocalStorage if you're running off a server?

Comment: @samwu it works fine locally,  I've got web sockets enabled in IIS.  My application startup has UseWebSockets set.  Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 What do you suggest I use to store values when components are not directly associated?  Should I be using SessionStorage?   Thanks for the replies,  sorry for the delay.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.